# Characteristic equation of product of upper and lower triangular matrices is $T^2-cT+I$. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is what is claimed as part of a solution in a book I'm working my way through.

$c$ is determined by the non-diagonal terms of the matrices.

I can't understand what they mean. Let's take, for example

$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & g
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
d & 0 \\
e & f
 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
ad+be & bf \\
ge & gf
\end{pmatrix}$

which has characteristic $\lambda^2 -\lambda (ad+be+gf)+adgf$.

Setting $\lambda=T$ and $ad+be+gf=c$, it's almost in the form I gave above. Does $adgf$ correspond to $I$? If so, isn't that potentially confusing notation, given that when discussing matrices $I$ usually means the identity matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is $P(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + c \lambda + d$, where $d$ is the determinant of your matrix.  They seem to be writing $P(T)$ where $T$ is the matrix itself, so this would be $T^2 + c T + d I$.  Now in your case it seems they want $d = 1$.  The determinant of the product of two matrices is the product of the determinants of the matrices.  Could it be that the particular two matrices they are multiplying each have determinant $1$?

Comment: Ok, got it. Yes, these matrices belong to $SL_2$ and hence their determinant must be 1. I hadn't thought that they'd be working with $P(T)$ rather than $P(\lambda)$ so was a bit confused to find the identity matrix in the middle of the characteristic polynomial.